# TLS 1.2 how to debug/reproduce

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2

I have an excel plugin written in c# that connects to a website hosted as an Azure app service with the following settings
[image: Azure app service TLS settings]

The plugin tries to download some content from the webapp using the following code

```
public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
            req.Proxy = GetProxyForConnection();
            //Add these, as we're doing a POST
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Method = "POST";
            //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
            os.Close();
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            if (resp == null) return null;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
```

this works perfectly on many computers, but we have a client who uses exclusively TLS 1.2 connection, this is what they wrote

*Our IT Security team have been removing TLS 1.1 from our environment – Microsoft’s recommendation.*

My question is how to reproduce this, how to make our dev environment TLS 1.2, and any hints on how to fix the issue?

thanks

P.S. the plugin is written in .net 4.0

Comment: Get [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (free software), enable / disable what you see fit.

Comment: `.net 4.0` means .Net Framework 4.0 - You have to update your app to target 4.7.2 / 4.8 (the latter is way better here).

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Comment: SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and has been disabled at server by  Microsoft Security push in June 2020.  You have to use TLS 1.2 or RTLS 1.3.  To force 1.2 or 1.3 in client suse System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;  This is a static method you can place at beginning of client.  Net 4.0 doesn't support TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 and you should use Net 4.7.2 or later where TLS is perform by operating system instead of in Net.  Using operating system makes sure windows security fixes are part of your TLS connections.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi for IIS Crypto this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET 4.0 doesn't support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2, is the why your code doesnt works.

Your applcation should be target to .NET Framework 4.7, better if it is 4.8.

As @jdweng said, the SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and has been disabled asap.

To simulate the issue its quite simple, use the [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) and uncheck the protocols, server and client side, see:

[image]

The changes made on [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/), changes the regedit, if you wanna know more about it, look at [Transport Layer Security (TLS) registry settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings)

Regards